# Slimでdivのclassを途中に切り替える方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim, adminlte

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。
viewはslimを使っていてAdminLTEテンプレートを適用しています。
AdminLTEテンプレートの中、フォームで使うclassがいくつかがあります。
まず、基本的にdiv.form-group、エラーが起こった時はdiv.form-group.has-warningなど。

自分がしたいのはvalidationを利用して、エラーメッセージを表示、それによってdiv.form-group.has-warningを使って入力のところのデザインもエラー表示したいんです。
ですが、基本はdiv.form-groupを使っているため、エラーがあるときだけdiv.form-group.has-warningに切り替える必要があります。ここをどうすればいいか教えていただきたいです。

下記は今のフォームのコードです。

```
div.box-body
  = form_for @book do |f|
    div.form-group
      .field
        = f.label :番号
        = f.text_field :book_num, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter...'
        = @book.errors.any? ? @book.errors.messages[:book_num][0] : ''
            .
            .
            .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby attributesで、エラーがあるときだけclass属性にhas-warningを設定してみてはいかがでしょうか
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/slim/frames#Ruby_attributes

```slim
div.box-body
  = form_for @book do |f|
    div.form-group class=(@book.errors.any? ? 'has-warning' : '')
      .field
        = f.label :番号
        = f.text_field :book_num, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter...'
        = @book.errors.any? ? @book.errors.messages[:book_num][0] : ''
            .
            .
            .
```

Comment: 動作確認しました！ありがとうございます。